# Adding a delay time for setProgressiveDownloadProgressBlock in AFNetworking Framework

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, afnetworking

I am downloading a large file using **AFDownloadRequestOperation** over **AFNetwork** and want the **setProgressiveDownloadProgressBlock** to be called after some delay or Time interval. How can i do that considering the code below?

```
       __weak MTCViewController *weakSelf= self;
       [_operation setProgressiveDownloadProgressBlock:^(AFDownloadRequestOperation *operation,
        NSInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpected, long long 
        totalBytesReadForFile, long long totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile) {

        [weakSelf performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateText:) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Progress = %i",percent] waitUntilDone:YES];
        }
```

**Because** i want this function to update data after some interval not thousands of time in a second

Comment: why you need the delay for a network call?

Comment: i dont need to add delay in network call.. i want to this function to update data after some interval not thousands of time in a second...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setProgressiveDownloadProgressBlock:` method gets called when the network operation fetch some data packets from the network.So calling inside it a method invokes that much times .

For your purpose You will have to keep a variable update it on each call and on reaching a certain value call your method